# Show that there exists a minimum spanning tree from a vertex always containing the shortest edge from that vertex

Tags: graph, minimum-spanning-tree, spanning-tree, weighted-graph

Suppose that e is an edge in a weighted graph that is incident to a vertex v such that the weight of e does not exceed the weight of any other edge incident to v. Show that there exists a minimum spanning tree containing this edge.

Comment: When asking about homework
(1) Be aware of your school policy: asking here for help may constitute cheating.
(2) Specify that the question is homework.
(3) Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first (include your code in your question).
(4) Ask about a specific problem with your existing implementation; [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

**Proof by Contradiction**

Assume that there exists a vertex v such that the MST does not use its smallest weight edge, e and instead uses another incident edge, let's call this x. Now, assume that we add the edge e back to the MST so that a cycle forms. We can now remove the previous edge used, x, on that cycle. At this point, we have another MST with a lower overall cost than the previously found spanning tree. This is a contradiction because the spanning tree with edge x was not actually an MST if it had a higher cost than the spanning tree with edge e.